# javascript spell checker recommendations

Tags: javascript, asp.net, spell-checking

we are after a JavaScript spell checker to run on our web app. 
it just needs to work on textareas and textboxes, no other checking is needed.

ideally it would also have the ability to add words to the global dictionary as we have quite a lot of in-house jargon.

unfortunately it also has to work on the beastly browser (IE6) ... crap

could anyone suggest a good option?

I have done a bit of looking, and the demo of the jquery php http://code.google.com/p/jquery-spellchecker/ one is exactly the sort of thing we are after, but to run on windows; don't really want to have to screw around with php just for this.

thanks

nat

**EDIT: i have found a asp.net port of the jquery spellchecker.. however it doesnt use the dictionary, instead uses googles one. which is great apart from not being able to add new words..
if anyone is interested its here: http://forums.asp.net/t/1519923.aspx
**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need PHP to run that plugin. The file checkspelling.php can be replaced with an ASP page. The code is short enough that translating it to asp shouldn't be a big deal (if you know PHP). The JS file would merely have to be updated to call checkspelling.asp rather than .php (or whatever you name it).

Side note: PHP can run on Windows.

Comment: hi pinkfloyd, thanks for that - good plan, ill give that a try. my php is a bit rusty, but im sure ill be able to sort it out. (yeah i have run wamp on windows afew time)

Answer (score 0):

Is it for an intranet site? If so, I suggest to use a plug-in for IE instead: if you will make a request to the server each time a user modifies a value of a textbox, it can result in a heavy load.

If I remember well, ieSpell still supports IE6.

On the other hand, if it is an internet website, you can always use the spell-checker you quoted in your question. Since it uses PHP, it can work both on Windows or Linux, so I don't see where's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check [SpellingCow](http://www.spellingcow.com/). Although it offers remote spell checking, it is still worth trying.