# Google Chrome Spell Check before event

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Is there an event fired by chrome before it actually changes the selected text during spellcheck.

onInput is fired after the change.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access Chrome spell-check suggestions in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30704264/how-to-access-chrome-spell-check-suggestions-in-javascript)

Comment: Unfortunately the answer is no, see the duplicate link for in-depth info, nothing has changed since.