# Check if text has error of typing

Tags: javascript, html

I wanna check, using JS, if a text typed inside an `<input>` contains that red underline that Chrome adds to the bottom of a word if it is typed wrong. Is it possible to check if the text is mispelled without the use of any library since chrome already tries to check if the text is typed correctly?

See example below.

[image]

Comment: Looks like this isn't possible... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30704264/how-to-access-chrome-spell-check-suggestions-in-javascript

Comment: Take a look at : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30704264/how-to-access-chrome-spell-check-suggestions-in-javascript

Comment: Ok thank you so much guys, but is this possible inside a chrome extension? maybe chrome extension has more privilege?