# Can I whitelist specific words to bypass built-in HTML text input spellchecking?

Tags: html, forms, validation, input, spell-checking

I've done quite a bit of searching for this functionality, but have had little success: is there some way to whitelist words that the HTML text input spellchecker mistakenly thinks are incorrectly spelled?

It's an awesome feature when it works, but it's fairly annoying when it falls short.  I'd like to keep it enabled for the cases where it's beneficial, while supplementing with a list of words that should not be flagged.

My specific use case is a nutrition tracking app I'm creating which allows for ingredient entry from various products, and it would be nice to flag misspellings like "blurberries" while letting odd words/phrases like "carnauba wax" through.  There are many ingredients like "carnauba wax" that are flagged even when spelled correctly.

Even while I draft this answer, "whitelist" is flagged as incorrect, even though a google search tries to correct "white list" or "white-list" to "whitelist".

[image]

[image]

Comment: Here's a four year old question that's about Chrome's spellchecker: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30704264/how-to-access-chrome-spell-check-suggestions-in-javascript  The answers there might shed some light on some of the issues you've run into... or it could be useless (sorry).